# Liferay 7 - Create a child theme of Classic Theme

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

Using the Liferay IDE, I have the necessity to create a new theme project that extends the Classic Theme of Liferay.

But there isn't a way to override specific templates of Classic Theme (at example with custom header, menu and footer), or add custom CSS, without lose future updates of Classic Theme in next releases of Liferay 7 CE ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, classic theme is a concrete theme and not even meant to extend - there is no promise of any stability. The next version might use a different design and still call it "classic".

You have two options:

- make "classic" yours by copying it wholesale (and rename it, of course) - then you're decoupled from future changes to the theme.
- Or extend it now and deal with (yet) unidentified future changes to
  it later.

You can still copy the theme once you find out that it's been changed in a non-backwards-compatible way (which probably won't happen before the next version).

The two themes that are explicitly meant to be extended (and that stay reasonably stable) are `_unstyled` and `_styled`. And if you look at "classic", it is an extension of `_styled`.

Comment: Ok, understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Marco How do you "make classic yours" ?

Comment: Hi @Victor, I simply copied the "Classic Theme" that is included in Liferay to a new folder in the same directory and replaced the references to "Classic Theme", as suggested by Olaf